# Angular2 Google Maps style marker

Tags: google-maps, angular

We are working with Angular2 Google Maps (https://angular-maps.com/)
I've gotten the Styled Google Maps to work already with this Plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/rv6udUOEedMxJejEpIW1

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleMapsAPIWrapper } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'styled-map'
})

export class StyledMap {

  constructor(private _wrapper: GoogleMapsAPIWrapper) {

    this._wrapper.getNativeMap().then((m) => {

      let stylesArray : any = [
         /* your styles here */
      ];

      m.setOptions({       
        streetViewControl: false, 
        styles: stylesArray
      });
    });
  }
}
```

However now I am looking to do exactly the same with the Marker, I need a label with my marker. When I do it the same way as with the styledMap, I can only get access to the `nativeMap` with `getNativeMap()`. But not to the native marker.

Any ideas?

Comment: want to set some icon instead of formal marker ? plunker not working throw not found ?

Comment: did you get it working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you are using https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps component to work with google maps.

As google doesn't support markers with labels out of the box, I have created custom component that uses markerwithlabel js library.

Create default "sebm" instance and place custom marker component inside it.

Example of map.component.html template:

```
<sebm-google-map
        [latitude]="lat"
        [longitude]="lng"
        [zoom]="zoom"
        [disableDefaultUI]="true"
        [zoomControl]="false"
        [streetViewControl]="false">

    <custom-map-marker
        *ngFor="let cluster of clusters; let i = index"
        [markersInCluster]="cluster.markers"
        [addressId]="cluster.address_id"
        [lat]="cluster.coordinates.lat"
        [lng]="cluster.coordinates.lng"
        [label]="cluster.price.raw"
        [isViewed]="true"
        (markerClick)="onMarkerClick($event)">
    </custom-map-marker>

</sebm-google-map>
```

Where custom-map-marker is my custom component that I have created.
I have created gist for you. You will have to cut off un-needed parts of code, and also this was written for RC4, so as from angular RC5 you will have to wrap component into module.

Code of gist:

https://gist.github.com/.../5e00519712fddb8ce206091a5a60e0f3

Later I could create working plnkr.

Result of provided gist should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: I almost have it working. You say I need to require the MarkerWithLabel.js file. This is clear. But I use node for module management and it throws this error:

Cannot find name 'google'.

How did you get it working with Bower?

Comment: Could you please create a working plunkr for this great work around ?

Comment: Above solution doe not work for me in angular2 app.
Can u plz provide plunkr link for the same.

Comment: Ok. I will create it as soon as I will have some free time.

Comment: Can't Implement this on latest version of angular2, will appreciate much if you could provide working plunkr link.

Comment: Yeah, since plunker is not yet ready, I know I've seen this map in production for one of Latvia-based real estate web page :D Now digging through the Internet to get it :D Sveiciens (Greetings) 

Comment: Hey anyone get solution for custom marker with label? If yes please share example or link.

Answer (score 1):

here's a workaround , from google maps API documentation, the label can either be a string or a MarkerLabel object specification, so instead of using string for label, specify the MarkerLabel object and feed it in as a variable eg:

```
let markerLabelObject = {
color: "red",
fontFamily: "monospace",
fontSize: "13",
fontWeight: "100",
text: element.names
}
this.markers.push({
lat: element.latitude,
label: markerLabelObject, //<<----the object you defined 
lng: element.longitude
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I Dont know which type of google map you are using , i have used primeng GMap where you can customize your marker with marker options like this

```
new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: 36.879466, lng: 30.667648}, title:"Konyaalti", icon: icon})
```

here you can asign any type of icon to google marker
see here
http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/gmap